# Remove the first 4 letters from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I am having a string as `G531 Other Dough Products`.

Here I want only `Other Dough Products`, reply me with code.

I tried with `substring` but that is not working.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: This is most probably due to a know bug in the 20 years-old NSString implementation which prevents it from performing the most basic operations on a string object. If you showed us the code where you used substring we *might* be able to help you work around this deep flaw in the frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually say what you tried but [substringFromIndex](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex%3a):

```
NSString *str = @"G531 Other Dough Products";
str = [str substringFromIndex:5];
```

should do the trick.

You'll probably find that you want to use 5 unless you want the leading space in your new string.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* s = [@"G531 Other Dough Products" substringFromIndex:5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "substringFromIndex" (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex:))

Answer (score 0):

He He, you can also do this as below,

```
NSString * newString = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)&"G531 Other Dough Products"[5] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```